# Transforming a logarithmic expression?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Do you know any nice way to rewrite $\log(1-e^{A})$?

Comment: Nicer, I don't think. Remember that $e^A >1$ if $A \geq 0$. If $A<0$ and very small, we can write approximations. Is it what you want ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no restrictions on A.

Comment: You could use the Taylor expansion to rewrite it, but at least to me this form is the nicest I know.

Comment: $\log(1-e^A) = \log ((e^{-A}-1)/e^{-A}) = \log(e^{-A}-1)-\log(e^{-A}) = \log(e^{-A}-1)+A$ but I do not think that this does help, does it? Or $\log(1-e^A) = \log(1-e^{A/2})+\log(1+e^{A/2})$.

Comment: between flawr and Claude's comments I believe you have to two cases $A>0$ and $|A|<1$?